# Is there any CSS code to customise the size of <hr> HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I created my own design in Adobe XD and would like to implement it in CSS code. What can I do to customise the size of `<hr>` element?

This is what I have tried:

```css
.line1 {
    border: 1px solid #5B5B5F;
}

.line2 {
    border: 1px solid #5B5B5F;
}

.line3 {
    border: 1px solid #5B5B5F;
}
```

```html
<div id="line1"><hr /></div>
<div id="line2"><hr /></div>
<div id="line3"><hr /></div>
```

Example of final result as expected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lmZ3.png

Could you please advise me on the better solution?

Comment: `.` is for classes, `#` is for IDs. Please read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_Selector#General_knowledge) or the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you for that! (Still a noob at this)
Also is there any way a can have a costumized space betting those 3 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HR tags are aligned to the center by default using `margin: auto`. Here is something that would work by playing with `%`. Note that I have replaced the ids with class.

```css
div hr{
  border: 1px solid #5B5B5F;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
.line-1 {
  width: 50%;
}
.line-2 {
  width: 75%;
}
.line-3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Upcoming Titles</h1>
  <hr class="line-1"/>
  <hr class="line-2"/>
  <hr class="line-3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `border` to none, the `margin` to `0` then you can style it.

- To change his color you can easily change the `background-color` property.
- To change his height you can edit the `height` property.
- To change his width you can edit the `width` property.

An example:

```css
.divider {
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<hr class="divider"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
div hr{
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: the "final result" link in the question is clearly about the width of the horizontal rule, not the height

Comment: It would be clear if you read the question to its entirety instead of racing to provide a low quality answer without any explanation. Feel free to edit your post with an answer that's not already out there and I'll gladly remove the downvote for an upvote, or delete it.